# Unity2D non-colliding rigidbody 2d objects with polygon collider 2d cause lag spikes when many overlap

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

I've build a small 2D space-shooter for my own personal education with a very simple enemy AI. It's the classic "point at the player and go" AI. I have the player bullets and enemies set up via the PhysicsManager and PhysicsManager2D to not interact with themselves. No enemies hit each other and no bullets hit each other (but bullets can hit enemies and the player/fixed objects can hit anything).

This seems to work and the game runs really well (even with an enormous number of objects on the screen) until the player uses the classic tactic of going in circles around the enemies until they cluster together then shooting at them. The game drops from 30+FPS down to 1-5FPS when a cluster of around 20-40 enemies ends up on top of each other. Having many many bullets on top of each other doesn't seem to be an issue, but this could be because it's difficult to make that happen consistently based on the speeds of the bullets.

Is there some additional collision checking that is happening that I haven't disabled? All enemies have a Rigidbody 2D and Polygon Collider 2D.

Comment: I haven't tried the PhysicsManager2D, but I imagine an option on a rigidbody setting it to not interact with itself, probably means the collision detections are happening, but the physics engine doesn't react to them. 40-odd ships, one on top of the other probably means quite a lot of collision detections.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm assuming. I just don't know how to tell it to ignore those collisions. Maybe it's not possible and I need to find a new way to manage my collisions, but that's awfully inconvenient!

Comment: I can't really think of any suggestions that might help. Have you tried asking on the unity answers website? http://answers.unity3d.com/